# compare billions rows and write into oracle table with spark

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-spark

Since I'm new to Apache Spark, I have to compare two tables and insert any changes that are discovered into a third table.
I've done it with a few records(10000*10000), and it works perfectly.
However, it took more than 4 hours to process 1 billion rows from each table, but no outcome.

table1 and table2 are different databases, and inserting in another database change_aud.

Any modifications or suggestions for improvement would be much welcomed

comparison taking more time.

32GB of 8 available cores.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("SparkandOracledbTest").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/dbname")
            .option("dbtable", "table1").option("user", "user").option("password", "password")
            .load();
    spark.conf().set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic");

    Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/dbname")
            .option("dbtable", "table2").option("user", "user").option("password", "password")
            .load();

    Dataset<Row> dfChange = df.except(df1);

    dfChange.write().partitionBy("TRACKING_ID").format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/dbname")
            .option("dbtable", "change_aud").option("user", "user").option("password", "password")
            .mode(SaveMode.Append).save();
```

Comment: Are the 2 tables Partitioned with the same/similar key, if yes then how many partitions are there, the reason is we can compare one partition of a table with the other partition.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal, I am not sure about the partition, i have not done any explicit partition.

Comment: Are all three tables in the same database, and schema? It's unclear from the changed names in your post. If they are then it would be much more efficient to do all the work in the database, rather than reading all the data out, comparing it in your application, and then writing it back again.

Comment: @AlexPoole all three tables are in different databases.